# How rare is a man in the middle attack?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, web-server, man-in-the-middle

I was wondering if I should set up a secure connection for the db administration application (phpmyadmin) for my sites.

They don't store credit cards nor anything that could be valuable for a hacker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're fairly rare, unless you access it over a wireless system. On the other hand, setting up a self-signed SSL certificate is pretty simple and raises the effort required to do a MITM attack, so there's no good reason *not* to do it.

Does it store passwords? Could compromising your (or some users') password compromise other sites? That's the main risk.

Comment: Agree.  SSL on database and website admin areas is generally a good idea and usually pretty simple to setup.

Comment: +1, agreed.  Furthermore, you're best off learning how to do this on the stuff that doesn't really matter, so you can do it properly when it DOES.  (And Rob's right, it's pretty easy)